# Min Max values using a linq query and select box

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I currently have a linq query in place that allows the user to display which 'carID' they wish. Now i want to implement a query that enables the user to be able to select the minimum and maximum engine size within a drop box saying 'min' and 'max'. I am unsure how to do this and would be grateful of some advise. Thanks

Comment: What is the type of the "Engine Size" field/column on the Car class/table? If it is not a simple Numeric/ordered Enumeration or Lookup Table, how would you sort them?

Comment: Hi Christopher thanks for the reply, the engine size is of type integer. Would I just do a similar query to above but store the minimum and maximum value? Its unclear to me on how to go about doing that

Comment: I can give you the SQL, I am not that good with LINQ: `Select * FROM TableCar WHERE EngineSize >= Minimum AND EngineSize <= Maximum`. With Minimum and Maximum being put in from the UI. If it is past early learning, you want to make sure to use Parametized Queries of course.

Comment: Getting Maximum is `SELECT MAX(EngineSize) FROM TableCar` MIN is coutner point. Basic Scalar Queries.

Comment: Thanks for your advice i will try implement the query using that information!

Comment: Are you trying to get the max and min from the list of cars? you can get the max and min from a list by doing var maxEngine= Model.CarID.Max(x=>x.EngineSize); and there is a similar Min function

Comment: Yes ThemDdlest im just unsure how to go about implementing it, thanks for your reply

Comment: You'd either need to make a Viewmodel that has fields for your max/min engines, or in your view you can run code to get the values from the Model/list: var maxEngine= Model.CarID.Max(x=>x.EngineSize); and then add the values to a drop down or something.

Comment: Yeah this helps me understand greatly, although im struggling to get my code to work with this in mind

Comment: @Campbell1 You should be able to do something like @Html.DisplayFor(x=>Model.CarID.Max(y=>y.EngineSize)) in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
var MaxEngineSize;
var MinEngineSize;

IEnumerable<Car> filteredCars = CarID.Where(x => x.EngineSize >= MinEngineSize && x.EngineSize <= MaxEngineSize)
```

If you want to use LINQ like a pro:

```
var MaxEngineSize;
var MinEngineSize;
bool EngineFilter(Car c) => c.EngineSize >= MinEngineSize && c.EngineSize <= MaxEngineSize;

var Manifacturer = "Toyota";
bool ManifacturerFiler(Car c) => c.Manifacturer == Manifacturer;


IEnumerable<Car> filteredCars = CarID.Where(EngineFilter)
                                     .Where(ManifacturerFiler);
```

In this way you can stack checks to create a filter for the cars you're displaying.

Comment: Thank you Alvin, this helps a lot. Only problem is i am trying to keep my queries similar as that is how i understand them best. Is there anyway you can 'dumb' it down to my level which makes it similar to the query above? again much appreciated!

Comment: Sure @Campbell1 . You're current query, transformed to LINQ is 
`var CarQuery = _context.Cars.Where(s => s.CarID == SearchCarID);`

Adding the min/max, it'd become
`var CarQuery = _context.Cars.Where(s => s.CarID == SearchCarID).Where(MinMaxFilter)` (using the lambda as shown above).
You see that it is just matter of perspective and the two queries become very similar, just an additional condition.

Comment: Great Alvin makes a lot more sense, would you be able to put it into my project so it works as i just tried and cannot grasp where where to put the query for it to work? For example could you take my example above and input your query so it runs?

Comment: Your code is a bit tricky to modify, as there is a lot of missing information. Consider creating simpler, Single Responsibility view models that contain the filtering algorithms. I wrote an example here: https://pastebin.com/DtNjk4vv I hope it is helpful.

Comment: ill write a new question and link you it bare with me, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400252/linq-query-to-find-minimum-and-maximum-values-selected-from-a-listbox-on-a-webp please find my new question to see if it gives more insight to what i am trying to do! thanks